# Java's TimerTask run() function not called when calling trait function inside

Tags: java, scala, timer, timertask, traits

I have the following code:

```
trait IntervalUpdate {

  val updateInterval: Long

  def onUpdateTask(): Unit

  val timer: Timer = new Timer()


  val timerTask = new TimerTask {
    override def run(): Unit =  onUpdateTask()
  }

  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, updateInterval, updateInterval)
}
```

I mix this trait into some classes and override the onUpdateTask method.

The problem is when I do this the `run()` function is simply never called.

However if I do something like: `override def run(): Unit =  println("message")` then it is called.

I feel this has something to do with `TimerTask` and `Timer` beeing Jave code and trying to use mixins but I think this should work.

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. I changed the code to this:

```
trait IntervalUpdate {

  val updateInterval: Long

  def onUpdateTask:() => Unit

  val timer: Timer = new Timer()


  val timerTask = new TimerTask {
    override def run(): Unit =  onUpdateTask()
  }

  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, updateInterval, updateInterval)
}
```